# how to move to another navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

I have a navigation controller, and I would like to move to another navigation controller. So basically when people logout they go to the login-register navigation controller. How can I get that done in ios?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can re-assign the root view controller like this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

Comment: I can't use self.window in a viewcontroller though?

Comment: You have to use `self.view.window`

Answer (score 1):

Why not present the login screen as a modal view controller? If the user logs out you present the modal view controller over the current screen. When the user logs in you dismiss the modal login view controller revealing the real part of the app.